# Spring boot kafka listening for every two hours and incase connection lost sending info

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

how can ı check if kafka server running or not for every two hours and incase of connection lost throw and event to the server which ı created method called "throwEven()" and listen kafka with 'listenKafkaEveryThisMs: 200000'

my Kafka yaml

kafka:

```
  url: localhost:9092
  topic: topicName
  groupid: conver
  offsetResetConfig: earliest
  concurrency: 1
  maxPollInternalMsConfig: 300000
  maxPollRecordsConfig: 30
  errorHandlerRetryCount: 5
  listenKafkaEveryThisMs: 200000
```

my KafkaConsumerConfig class

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {
    
    @Value("${kafka.concurrency}")
    private String concurrency;
    
    @Value("${kafka.url}")
    private String kafkaUrl;
    
    @Value("${kafka.groupid}")
    private String groupid;
    
    @Value("${kafka.offsetResetConfig}")
    private String offsetResetConfig;
    
    @Value("${kafka.maxPollInternalMsConfig}")
    private String maxPollInternalMsConfig;
    
    @Value("${kafka.maxPollRecordsConfig}")
    private String maxPollRecordsConfig;
    
    @Value("${kafka.errorHandlerRetryCount}")
    private String retryCount;

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaUrl);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupid);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, offsetResetConfig);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, Integer.parseInt(maxPollInternalMsConfig));
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, Integer.parseInt(maxPollRecordsConfig));
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }
 
    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> 
      kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
          new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency(Integer.parseInt(concurrency));
        factory.getContainerProperties().setSyncCommits(true);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);

        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckOnError(false);
        factory.setStatefulRetry(true);
        factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(Integer.parseInt(retryCount)));
        RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
        retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(new AlwaysRetryPolicy());
        retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(new ExponentialBackOffPolicy());
        
        factory.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate);
        
        return factory;
    }
}
```

my KafkaConsumer class

```
 @Service
    public class KafkaConsumer implements ConsumerSeekAware {
    
    
        private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaConsumer.class);
    
        @KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${kafka.topic}'}", groupId = "#{'${kafka.groupid}'}")
        public void consume(String message, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) Integer partition,
                            @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) Long offset, Acknowledgment ack, KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter) {


   if (!kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.isRunning()) {

            throwEvent();
        }
    
   
    
            try {
                mobileSubscriptionService.processMessage(message, ack, null);
    
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    
        @Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${kafka.listenKafkaEveryThisMs}")
        private void throwEvent() {
    
            Map<String, String> eventDetails = new HashMap<>();
            eventDetails.put("eventDetailsKey", "eventDetailsValue");
    
            AppDynamicsEventUtil.publishEvent("eventSummary", EventSeverityStatus.INFO, EventTypeStatus.CUSTOM, eventDetails);
        }
```

I really dont know what I should use to listen kafka server runnig or not

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For checking cluster connection state, most straightforward would be [`AdminClient.describeCluster()`](https://kafka.apache.org/24/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/Admin.html#describeCluster--)

Alternatively, you can [hook some check into Actuator](https://medium.com/dna-technology/kafka-consumers-health-check-in-spring-boot-actuator-d00f9017e89d)

Comment: Thank you I deleted htp on yaml. Can you chack my services. ı did not find nothing wrong but somehow it does not listen how can ı use "AdminClient.describeCluster()" on my method Thank you

Comment: Dont understand what you mean. `@KafkaListener` and `AdminClient` are completely different things. You'd need a new `@Bean` for an Adminclient

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just want to listen Kafka and if any error, I want to throw an event thats all so , for this !kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.isRunning() I used that method, however everytime sends false